# Why don't the app name display when I use Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar in PreferenceActivity?

Tags: android, android-studio

I have set android:label="@string/app_name", and the app name can be displayed correctly in CleanupAbout.java when the class extends AppCompatActivity.

I customized a PreferenceActivity CleanupPreference.java which extends PreferenceActivity, but I found the app name disappear, why? Thanks!

**App Name OK in CleanupAbout.java**

[image]

**App Name disappear in CleanupPreference.java**

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="info.dodata.messagecleanup" >

    <
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

        <activity
            android:name="ui.CleanupMain"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>


        <activity android:name="ui.CleanupAbout"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="ui.CleanupAbout" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>


        <activity android:name="ui.CleanupPreference"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="ui.CleanupPreference" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.PREFERENCE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

**Style.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">

    </style>

    <!-- Application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
        <!-- All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level can go here. -->
    </style>

    <style name="myTextLarge">
        <item name="android:textAppearance">?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">21sp</item>
    </style>

    <style name="myTextMedium">
        <item name="android:textAppearance">?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">16sp</item>
    </style>

    <style name="myTextSmall">
        <item name="android:textAppearance">?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall</item>
    </style>

    <style name="myTextDesciption">
        <item name="android:textAppearance">?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/violet</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

**CleanupPreference.java**

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

public class CleanupPreference extends PreferenceActivity{
    private AdView adView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.cleanup_preference_resource);
        setContentView(R.layout.cleanup_preference);
    }

}
```

**cleanup_preference_resource.xml**

```
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:key="AppPreference"
    android:summary="@string/PreferenceSummary"
    android:title="@string/Preference" >


    <CheckBoxPreference
       android:defaultValue="true"
       android:key="IsWriteToLog"
       android:title="@string/WriteToLogTitle"
       android:summary="@string/WriteToLogSummary"
       android:layout="@layout/my_preference_item"
    />    

</PreferenceScreen>
```

**cleanup_preference.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/border_ui"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        ads:adUnitId="@string/ad_unit_id" />


    <ListView android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_above="@+id/linearLayout1"
        >
    </ListView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="4" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnClosePreference"
            style="@style/myTextMedium"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/BtnReturn" >
        </Button>
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**my_preference_item.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
    android:paddingLeft="8dip"
    android:paddingRight="?android:attr/scrollbarSize" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:minWidth="0dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:visibility="gone" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+android:id/icon"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:minWidth="48dp"
            android:paddingRight="8dip" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:paddingBottom="6dip"
        android:paddingRight="8dip"
        android:paddingTop="6dip" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+android:id/title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ellipsize="marquee"
            android:fadingEdge="horizontal"
            android:singleLine="true"
            style="@style/myTextMedium" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+android:id/summary"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@android:id/title"
            android:layout_below="@android:id/title"
            android:maxLines="4"
            style="@style/myTextSmall"
            android:textColor="?android:attr/textColorSecondary" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <!-- Preference should place its actual preference widget here. -->

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+android:id/widget_frame"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:minWidth="48dp"
        android:orientation="vertical" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**CleanupAbout.java**

```
import android.content.pm.PackageManager.NameNotFoundException;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.text.method.LinkMovementMethod;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class CleanupAbout extends AppCompatActivity {

    private AdView adView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.cleanup_about);  

    }

}
```

**cleanup_about.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/border_ui"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        ads:adUnitId="@string/ad_unit_id" />


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_above="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:paddingTop="12dip"
        android:paddingLeft="7dip"
        android:paddingRight="7dip"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/appversion"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvVersion"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="2dip"
            android:text="" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/myabout"
            android:layout_marginTop="17dip"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvMyLink"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="2dip"
            android:text="@string/mylink" />


    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:weightSum="4" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnReturn"
            style="@style/myTextMedium"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/BtnReturn" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `PreferenceFragment` and add [toolbar](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toolbar.html) to your `cleanup_preference.xml`

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/border_ui"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        app:popupTheme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light" >

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        ads:adUnitId="@string/ad_unit_id" />

    ......

</RelativeLayout>
```

and set `toolbar` as `actionbar` in your `CleanupPreference.java`

```
public class CleanupPreference extends AppCompatActivity {

    ......

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.cleanup_preference);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.fragment_container, new SettingsFragment())
                .commit();
    }

    public static class SettingsFragment extends PreferenceFragment {
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.cleanup_preference_resource);
        }
    }
}
```

and dont forget include `appcompat v7` in your dependencies

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
```

Comment: Thanks.  But maybe your code isn't correct.  In order to use setSupportActionBar , you must use a class extends from ActionBarActivity ,  at present my class extends referenceActivity

Comment: `PreferenceActivity` extends plain `Activity` not support `AppCompatActivity` so you can't expect it to behave exactly as your other activities. You need [`AppCompatPreferenceActivity`](https://github.com/android/platform_development/blob/master/samples/Support7Demos/src/com/example/android/supportv7/app/AppCompatPreferenceActivity.java) for this. Put this class in your project and let your preference activity extend it.

Comment: my mistake, see updated answer. Actually I use `PreferenceFragment` to show my App Setting.